Is there a reason why destroying an actor in UE5 is crashing the engine?
I have created an actor containing an on collision method to destroy itself. The on collision method works in by itself when triggering a UE_LOG, when triggering the destroy method it freezes before crashing the engine. I am quite certain that it must be a code issue rather than a blueprint settings problem because of this.
c++:
#include "MechanicMike_BreakableBlock.h"

#include "MechanicMike.h"
#include "PaperSpriteComponent.h"
#include "Components/BoxComponent.h"

// Sets default values
AMechanicMike_BreakableBlock::AMechanicMike_BreakableBlock()
{
    // Set this actor to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    MySprite = CreateDefaultSubobject<UPaperSpriteComponent>(TEXT("Breakable Block"));
    MyBreakableTrigger = CreateDefaultSubobject<UBoxComponent>(TEXT("Breakable Trigger"));
    RootComponent = MyBreakableTrigger;
    MySprite->SetupAttachment(RootComponent);
}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void AMechanicMike_BreakableBlock::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
    MyBreakableTrigger->OnComponentHit.AddDynamic(this, &AMechanicMike_BreakableBlock::OnBlockHit);
    
}

// Called every frame
void AMechanicMike_BreakableBlock::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

}

void AMechanicMike_BreakableBlock::OnBlockHit(UPrimitiveComponent* HitComponent, AActor* OtherActor,
    UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, FVector NormalImpulse, const FHitResult& Hit)
{
    if (OtherActor->IsA(AMechanicMike::StaticClass()))
    {
        BlockDestroy();
    }
}

void AMechanicMike_BreakableBlock::BlockDestroy()
{
    if (!IsPendingKillPending())
    {
        Destroy();
    }
}

Any help or support would be appreciated. Thanks

is unreal engine garbage collector aware of your class? did you set proper UCLASS macro?

@blonded04 Would that be UPROPERTY within the header file? if so then yes

It is unclear how the code example relates to the question asked. Please provide a minimal reproducible example to highlight what exactly causes the problem.

Could your texture be too complex? Is it in nanite? Nanite helps reduce lag. What file extension is it using? Can you give me the texture pack. I have Unreal Engine 5.3.2, so, I can solve it for you and give you back a file with problems solved.
